# Angular 7 integration with D3: adding click listener throws error

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I need to add click event listener to dynamically created d3 element. However I get error 'function doesn't exist'

```
export class MyComponent{
 public ngOnInit(){
   this.modelConfig = {
   transformer() {
   const column = this.columns.find((col) => col.field === 'id');
   if (column) {
          column.element = document.createElement('button');
          column.render = (element, d) => {
          const d3Element = d3.select(element).select('button');
          d3Element.attr('type', 'button');
          d3Element.on('click', () => {       
               this.editItem(d.value);
          });
       };
      }
    },
  };
 }
 public editItem(id: string): void{
   console.log(id);
 }
}
```

However it was transformed I get this error in console:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: _this.editItem is not a function
```

The compiled code in browser sources looks like this:

```
MyComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
   this.modelConfig = {
   transformer: function () {
   var _this = this;
   var column = this.columns.find(function (col) { return col.field === 'id'; });
   if (column) {
   column.element = document.createElement('button');
   column.render = function (element, d) {
   var d3Element = d3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["select"](element).select('button');
   d3Element.attr('type', 'button');
   d3Element.on('click', function () {
         _this.editItem(d.value);
        });
      };
    }
  },
 };
};
```

My JavaScript knowledge is not very good, can someone explain why `this` was transformed to `_this` and why class function can't be found?

Comment: Is function editItem is defined in that file.

Comment: The compiled code indeed has something transpiled as `var _this = this;` hence that shouldn't be an issue, Just make sure that you have the `editItem` function definition in place or not.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya hi, yes. the function is in same file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` should be cached one more level up to point it to the component. I am not sure how `modelConfig.transform()` works or how `column.render()` works, but one way can be caching the component reference first and then using it.

In your case, `this` is probably pointing to `modelConfig` or `transformer` depending on how they are *called*. You can find that out by simply doing `console.log(this)` inside your click handler.

```
export class MyComponent{
 public ngOnInit(){
   const component = this; // cache a reference here
   this.modelConfig = {
   transformer() {
   const column = this.columns.find((col) => col.field === 'id');
   if (column) {
          column.element = document.createElement('button');
          column.render = (element, d) => {
          const d3Element = d3.select(element).select('button');
          d3Element.attr('type', 'button');
          d3Element.on('click', () => {       
               component.editItem(d.value);
          });
       };
      }
    },
  };
 }
 public editItem(id: string): void{
   console.log(id);
 }
}
```